# Looking for edid file for Dell S2240L

Tags: dell, resolution

This is my first posting in askubuntu.

My Monitor is Dell S2240L. My monitor has corrupted edid information. It's full resolution is 1920x1080 but stuck at 1024x768 and 1280x720 as the 2 highest resolution. custom xrandr mode doesn't work at 1080p and turns the monitor black. Re-install of Ubuntu/any variant or even windows doesn't work. Windows shows the option for 1920x1080, but whenever I select it the monitor turns black and remains that way. It would be nice if someone can provide provide edid data (HDMI to dvi) from correctly working Dell S2240L?

Motherboard: Gigabyte 880 GM UD2H
CPU : AMD Phenom X965BE
Using onboard AMD Radeon HD 4250 with open driver.

**Procedure:**

Connect your monitor with HDMI to dvi cable. Under Linux(Ubuntu) install read-edid

`sudo apt-get install read-edid`

package and issue these 2 commands.

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid 

sudo get-edid > edid.bin
```

First command will get the edid information and decode it & see if it correct or not. If it's not correct, you will get warning/error.

Second command will make a binary file from edid information.

I need (HDMI to dvi) information. Make a tar.gz archive & upload it on Dropbox/Google drive or any other file sharing sites. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have the same monitor connected via DVI-to-HDMI cable:

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "DELL S2240L"
ModelName "DELL S2240L"
VendorName "DEL"
# Monitor Manufactured week 32 of 2014
# EDID version 1.3
# Digital Display
DisplaySize 480 270
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "true"
Horizsync 30-83
VertRefresh 56-76
# Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
#Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz

#Extension block found. Parsing...
Modeline    "Mode 13" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
Modeline    "Mode 1" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 2" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
Modeline    "Mode 5" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
Modeline    "Mode 6" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
Modeline    "Mode 7" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
Modeline    "Mode 8" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
Modeline    "Mode 9" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
Modeline    "Mode 10" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 11" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
Modeline    "Mode 12" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 14" 74.25 1920 2008 2052 2200 540 542 547 562 +hsync +vsync interlace
Modeline    "Mode 15" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
Modeline    "Mode 16" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 13"
EndSection
```

You can download EDID file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rcp39bkjw15z5i/edid.tar.gz?dl=0).